# How to remove the last part of a string after underscore using Windows command line

Tags: cmd

I have a file as "RAAAAAAV.KKK9.Z01_YYYYMMDDhhmmss". I want to remove the last part after the underscore"_" using a one liner dos command. Please help.

Output required:
RAAAAAAV.KKK9.Z01

Comment: Have you already tried something ?

Comment: What operating system are you using? That's an unlikely filename for MS-DOS.

Comment: @RossRidge - Given that my answer worked for the OP, it most definitely is Windows, and not DOS. I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The following works

```
@echo off
set var=RAAAAAAV.KKK9.Z01_YYYYMMDDhhmmss
set "var=%var:_="&rem %
set var
```

Comment: Please give me a one liner code which will remove everything after the last underscore (_)

Answer (score 1):

To rename a specific file:

```
ren "RAAAAAAV.KKK9.Z01_20151009231015" *.Z01
```

To rename all files with extension like Z01_timestamp:

```
ren *.Z01_?????????????? *.Z01
```

To rename all files where the beginning of the extension is unknown:

```
for %F in (*.???_??????????????) do @for /f "delims=_" %X in ("%~xF") do @ren "%F" "%~nF%X"
```

If used in a batch script, then percents must be doubled:

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.???_??????????????) do for /f "delims=_" %%X in ("%%~xF") do ren "%%F" "%%~nF%%X"
```

***EDIT - 2015-10-10***

If you really want to have precise control over which files get renamed, then you can use my [JREN.BAT regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. The following simple one liner strips off the underscore and timestamp from any file that has an extension consisting of any combination of letters and digits, followed by an underscore, followed by a 14 digit timestamp.

```
jren "(\.[A-Z0-9]+)_\d{14}$" $1 /i
```

Comment: Hi The following two qualifiers are dynamic in nature "KKK9.Z01" so i cannot use *.Z01

Comment: @user3032562 - If you had put more effort into your question, then you could have been more specific. However, I anticipated that issue, which is why I provided the last two options in my answer. If you took the time to read all of my answer, you would realize it handles the dynamic nature that you neglected to specify.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe already late, but I will share my founding anyway for benefit to others.

You can use batch sub-procedure/function

```
:leftStr STRING SEPARATOR RESULT_VAR
::get left string before some specific SEPARATOR
set "STRING=%~1"                get arg1
set "RIGHT=%STRING:*%~2=%"      anything after arg2
set "%~3=!STRING:%~2%RIGHT%=!"  strip that substr
exit /b
```

Then you can call it from other places, works even inside for loop with delayedExpansion enabled.

```
..
call :leftStr "left_right" "_" varname
echo !varname!
@rem varname = left
```

note: this is not a fancy function, no error checking or such. You'd better make sure your input string, separator, return_var is already valid or no conflict with any other.

EDIT: forgot to mention, this is for arbitrary length string and separator, for a simple, fixed length you can just use %var:~-N1,N2% (with negative N1)